# work/worked and know/known?

Tags: grammar, present-perfect, perfect-constructions

Normally, when we use ***stative verbs*** in perfect tense, we prefer *simple perfect tense*, *not perfect continuous*, and we know that they mean the same thing.

I have **worked** here for 3 years. *or* I have been **working** here for 3 years.

I have only **known** her for two days. but this sentence has no progressive form. Because the verb is a stative verb.

What about '' work '' ? Can you explain with a few examples?

FURTHER EXPLANATION:

I actually meant to say that sentences with the stative verb are continuous. But when using other verbs, can we use both continuity and until now?

For example :

I have worked here for 3 years. (I've just quit my job. and now I've gotten another job.?

I have worked here for 3 years. ( I'm still working.)

So can we think like this with stative verbs?

I have believed that you're a good person (continuity) ( and still believe)

I have believed that you're a good person. (past) ( and now i dont believe ) ???

I‘ve been happy all my life. (continuity)

I‘ve been happy all my life ( past ) ( and now i am not ) ???

Comment: If you have quit your job, you would say "I worked **there** for three years", not **here** (unless you were revisiting your old workplace!). In your other examples, the past continuous is only appropriate if the statement is still true or if it was true for periods of time. "I have believed it all my life (and still do)." "I have been happy sometimes (but not always)."

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the scope of your question.

Here is what I think:

- The Present perfect continuous focuses on the time that has passed. You want to emphasize that you have worked in this company for **three** years.
- The Present perfect simple is more neutral in this context. To say that you worked here in the past, but you are still working today.